# GStreamer. Probe after rtph265pay never called

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

i have rtsp server and i want to extend rtp buffer header. For this purpose i added probe to src of  rtph265pay, but it never called. My pipeline:

```
( appsrc name=vsrc ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=NV12 !
omxh265enc MeasureEncoderLatency=true bitrate=20000000 control-rate=2 !
rtph265pay name=pay0 pt=96 )
```

Code where i attach probe:

```
static GstPadProbeReturn test_probe (GstPad *pad, GstPadProbeInfo *info,
gpointer user_data)
{
    cout << "i'm here";
}



 void mediaConfigure (GstRTSPMediaFactory* factory, GstRTSPMedia* media,
gpointer user_data)
{
        GstElement *element, *rtph265pay; GstPad *pad;
        element = gst_rtsp_media_get_element (media);
        rtph265pay = gst_bin_get_by_name_recurse_up (GST_BIN (element), "pay0");
        pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (rtph265pay, "src");
        gst_pad_add_probe (pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER,
        (GstPadProbeCallback) test_probe, NULL, NULL);
        gst_object_unref (pad);
}
```

If i set "sink" instead of "src", probe works, but i need "src" to change rtp buffer header...
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because the rtph265pay's src pad isn't linked to any other pad - meaning rtph265pay is the end of the pipeline - the element doesn't pass any buffers to its src pad? 
Try and attach a fakesink after the rtph265pay.

Comment: thanks, you was right, i added identity element after pay and everything works now. but i have one more question. how should i add data to extension if it's bigger than 16 bits? for example i want to add long long. Does it means that i should split my data and call set  extension function 4 times?

Comment: I’m actually not sure - when I used it, I needed to pass two values, each 16 bit. So, because I didn’t have time to experiment and didn’t want to mess up something, I split the pipeline into two streams (each with its own rtph264pay) and set the x value in the extension of one, and the y value on the extension of the other.

Sorry I couldn’t help with this question, and I’m glad I could help with your first one :)